# Determine if there exist rational number a and irrational number A such that $A^3+aA^2+aA+a=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Determine if there exist a rational number a and irrational number A such that $A^3+aA^2+aA+a=0$. If so, can we say something about them? Are there infinitely many of them?

Comment: @Peter I'm pretty sure they mean real irrational. Your example is cheating.

Comment: @Peter But it's not real. While you're technically correct, I've never heard $i$ referred to as an irrational number. It's a Gaussian integer.

Comment: @PeterForeman A matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ also cannot be expressed as ${p \over q}$, yet we don't call matrices irrational. The term refers specifically to $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number

Comment: @PeterForeman What specific phrase are you refering to?

Comment: @PeterForeman Note in the Gelfond constant article that they refer to $i$ as not rational rather than irrational. Only real numbers are called irrationals throughout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any integer $a$ except $0$ or $1$,  the polynomial $x^3 + a x^2 + a x + a$ has no rational roots.  Any rational root $A$ would have to be an integer (by Gauss's lemma, or the Rational Root Theorem). Now $A^3 + a A^2 + a A + a = 0 $ means 
$$a = - \frac{A^3}{A^2 + A + 1} = -A + 1 - \frac{1}{A^2 + A + 1}$$
which, if $A$ is an integer, is not an integer unless $A = 0$ (corresponding to $a=0$) or $A = -1$ (corresponding to $a = 1$): otherwise $A^2 + A + 1 = (A + 1/2)^2 + 3/4 > 1$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like $A=i, a=1$, you can work with $a=-n$, $n>1$ square-free integer.  By Eisenstein criterion, the polynomial $x^3-nx^2-nx-n$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so the positive root $A$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $X^3+pX^2+pX+p$ has no root if $p$ is a prime number, for example (the only potential roots are $1,-1,p,-p$. Check they are not).

But this polynomial has at least one real root $A$, since it has degree 3.